# Monitoring options for QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I want to monitor QuestDB instance status, ideally in Prometheus. Would be good to see queries rate, ingestion speed, avg response time, etc.

Is there a way to get this information out of QuestDB? I see only docs about [minimum HTTP server](https://questdb.io/docs/operations/health-monitoring/) which returns back HTTP code 200 if the server is up, I can integrate it as a black box in Prometheus is there anything else I can do to monitor the instance?

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of QuestDB support Prometheus metrics. How to enable them?

1. Add this to QuestDB configuration: `metrics.enabled=true`. This will expose the Prometheus metrics endpoint `/metrics` on port 9003
2. Add this to your Prometheus configuration:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'questdb'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'questdb'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['127.0.0.1:9003']
```

You have to replace the `127.0.0.1` with the IP where QuestDB is running.

If you are running QuestDB inside Docker then pass this environment variable `QDB_METRICS_ENABLED=TRUE` instead of editing the config file to enable the metrics endpoint. Passing an environment variable is simpler than editing a file inside a container image.

Details are covered in the [QuestDB Documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/third-party-tools/prometheus)

Answer (score 0):

Just came to say a few extra prometheus metrics were added in the latest release https://github.com/questdb/questdb/releases/tag/6.5.3